# Is it relevant to use both feature normalizer_fn and batch normalization?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

Is it relevant to use both feature normalizer_fn and batch normalization like following ?

```
 feature_columns_complex_standardized = [         
          tf.feature_column.numeric_column("my_feature", normalizer_fn=lambda x: (x - xMean) / xStd)
        ]
```

```
          model1 = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns_complex_standardized,
                                            hidden_units=[512,512,512],
                                            optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, beta1= 0.9,beta2=0.99, epsilon = 1e-08,use_locking=False),
                                            weight_column=weights,
                                            dropout=0.5,
                                            activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax,
                                            n_classes=10,
                                            label_vocabulary=Action_vocab,
                                            model_dir='./Models9/Action/',
                                            loss_reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE,
                                            config=tf.estimator.RunConfig().replace(save_summary_steps=10),
                                            batch_norm=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you get it wrong, as `Normalization` is one of the methods used to bring features in a dataset to the same scale, where `batch normalization` is used for solving the problem of `internal covariate shift` where each hidden unit’s input distribution changes every time there is a parameter update in the previous layer.

So you can use both at the same time.